# Getting println error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, println

I'm beginning programming with Java, and it seems Eclipse is giving me errors from day one.
Here's my hello, world program:

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println(“Hello, World!”);
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to run the code, though, `println` gets a red underline, and the line is marked with a red "x" symbol. Eclipse tells me that "`println` cannot be resolved".

This syntax lines up perfectly with various Hello World programs around the web, as well as the one in the book I'm learning Java from. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of double quotes is that?

Comment: Ordinary double quotes, HTML code &quot;

Comment: That is NOT how they are/were displaying in your question!

Comment: It turns out that my keyboard layout was set to a different language from an earlier project; what usually produces regular quotes made curly quotes.

Comment: @StephenC well, after your edit, there's no question.

Comment: @M.M. It wasn't my edit.  In fact my "edit" was a glitch.  Anyway I've rolled it back so that people can see the original question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Hello World" seems to be surrounded by curly quotes instead of straight quotes in your code.

The reason you're seeing a compilation error is that Java determines which method to use based on both the name of the method and the types of the arguments. println, for instance, takes a String (or a bool, int or other types documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println() ).

Your code seems to pass in an unknown type, so println(curly string) cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 3):

The quotes surrounding Hello, World! are not the right type.